# Is there a way to apply the greater than ( '>' ) operator to a list in a soql query?

Tags: apex

> ```
> set<decimal> volume = new set<decimal>();
>     
> for(QuoteLineItem record:newrecords){
>    volume.add(record.Quantity);
> }
>
> [select From_Quantity__c where From_Quantity__c > :volume];
> ```

Can we use Greater than (`>`) operator for comparing set/list values?

It is not working, if we can't use it then what is an alternative way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`From_Quantity__c` is a single-value field, so it is not possible to compare it to set of values. For example, you have `From_Quantity__c = 1` and `volume = {0, 2}`. Is `1 > {0, 2}`? It makes no sense.

You should compare only matching values. So, for example, get greatest `record.Quantity` for `Decimal volume` or get sum of quantities, as it suites for your business case. But you cannot compare a single-value field `From_Quantity__c` with set of values.

UPDATE with code sample for maxVolume:

```
Decimal maxVolume = 0.0;

for (QuoteLineItem record : newrecords) {
    if (record.Quantity > maxVolume) {
        maxVolume = record.Quantity;
    }
}

for (Mode__c record : [SELECT From_Quantity__c FROM Mode__c WHERE From_Quantity__c > :maxVolume]) {
    
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code , to compare the values for my use case

Comment: How to get greatest of record.Quantity in apex, i have used MAX also it is not working

Comment: @SalesforceEmail I have updated the answer, please, take a look.

Comment: Great Answer , suddenly i am not able to strike it.